# command button click on Userform enter textbox to cell, then loop columns per click

Tags: vba, excel, ranged-loops

I'm very new to VBA.  I've created a userform that has textboxes that need to transfer  textbox data to a range of cells. The range I need it to work on is Columns for example C8:AG8  so the data in the text box once entered and clicked  will loop to the next column to repeat the process.  I need the loop to work from column to column, not row to row.  Thank you.

So far I have the below however, This only populates one time:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Range("C8") = TextBox1.Value
    Range("C9") = TextBox2.Value
    Range("C10") = TextBox3.Value
    Range("C11") = TextBox4.Value
    Range("C12") = TextBox5.Value
    Range("C13") = TextBox6.Value
    Range("C14") = TextBox7.Value
    Range("C15") = TextBox8.Value
    Range("C16") = TextBox9.Value
    Range("C17") = TextBox10.Value
    Range("C18") = TextBox11.Value
    Range("C19") = TextBox12.Value
    Range("C20") = TextBox13.Value
    Range("C21") = TextBox14.Value
    Range("C22") = TextBox15.Value
    Range("C23") = TextBox16.Value
    Range("C24") = TextBox17.Value
    Range("C25") = TextBox18.Value
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would probably do it:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim i As Integer

For i = 3 To 33 'Columns C to AG

    Cells(8, i) = TextBox1.Value
    Cells(9, i) = TextBox2.Value
    Cells(10, i) = TextBox3.Value
    Cells(11, i) = TextBox4.Value
    Cells(12, i) = TextBox5.Value
    Cells(13, i) = TextBox6.Value
    Cells(14, i) = TextBox7.Value
    Cells(15, i) = TextBox8.Value
    Cells(16, i) = TextBox9.Value
    Cells(17, i) = TextBox10.Value
    Cells(18, i) = TextBox11.Value
    Cells(19, i) = TextBox12.Value
    Cells(20, i) = TextBox13.Value
    Cells(21, i) = TextBox14.Value
    Cells(22, i) = TextBox15.Value
    Cells(23, i) = TextBox16.Value
    Cells(24, i) = TextBox17.Value
    Cells(25, i) = TextBox18.Value

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you,  I have another issue as well. (much bigger)  to start with I have